I Have a LWC DataTable which I am using inside a ScreenFlow to display the value on the UI but for mobile I need a different UI. How can achieve that?


I have created a LWC component for Desktop UI and now I need a totally different UI for mobile device but I am unable to create it. I am attaching the desktop UI Screenshot that I have already created and also attaching the required mobile device UI that I have to create. I have used XML file where I have defined few property to define the columns name.

To create custom UI, use a mixture of the LWC Components and the SLDS Classes.
You will have to write your own loop - see Render Lists - and take care of the layout details such as acting on button clicks. And decide how to consume your XML file.
So overall a lot more work and detail than using an LWC that takes care of everything.
If you are willing to accept a compromised design for mobile, take a look at the answer here How to present a lightning-datatable on mobile devices?.
Also see Will there be a responsive datatable component soon?.
